# How to retrieve a variable from an "object"

Tags: php, arrays, object

The code below is generating a payment in a PSP db. The "print_r($result)" will give a printout like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjsQQ.png

My question is; How do i easiest retrieve the "id" (value=10101870) and put it into a variable?

I'm not sure if i should just json or something similar, as i'm not familiar with this way of storing data (is it an "object" or a special type of array?)

```
   $params = array(
       "currency"            => "DKK",
       "order_id"           => "1234567890",
   );                                                                    
   $data_string = http_build_query($params, '&'); 

   $headers = array(
          'Accept-Version: v10',
          'Accept: application/json', 
          'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode(":HIDDEN_KEY")
      );                                                                                  

   $ch = curl_init('https://api.quickpay.net/payments');                                                                      
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);      
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   if(!curl_exec($ch)){
       die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);

   print_r($result);
```

Comment: Looks like JSON, use `json_decode()`.

Comment: I'm not really into this, and my problem is that it's located in a place where it's quite difficult to test, so i would need someone to help me with the exact code, i'm afraid... Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

So your `$result` won't have the `HTTP` header included and leave you only with the `json` payload.

Then decode the `json` string and access the `id` member

```
$object = json_decode($result);
print $object->id;
```

Comment: This is what turned out to work for me. Thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it did not print Array or Object from the `print_r`, it seems like a string in json format. What you can do to ge the ID is the following:

```
$data=json_decode($result, true);
echo $data['id'];
```

Or if you want to use objects:

```
$data=json_decode($result);
echo $data->id;
```

Comment: For some reason i couldn't make any of these work, so i went with Alex' method. Anyhow thanks for replying quickly! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's most probably because you didn't remove `CURLOPT_HEADER` which would have outputted the extra data and the `json_decode` wouldn't have worked ;)